# How to configure Azure Storage Gen 2 for Azure Databricks

Tags: azure-storage, azure-databricks

I'm trying to mount data lake with Databricks. My goal is to build data lake. I wonder why format of my url is different from documentation.What is meaning of filesystem and dfs?

I tried to create data lake with Azure Storage Gen2. Enabled hierarchy and started to create directories.
I noticed that file url includes word "blob".

This is my url currently:
https://datalakestagingtest.blob.core.windows.net/staging/manufacturers/nissan/micra.csv

I see that format is different in DataLake documentation where url may
be abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/

Reference:
https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html

Comment: In Azure databricks, it uses Hadoop  File System. And In Hadoop, we need to use  abfs scheme to access Azure Storage Gen 2. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-abfs-driver

Comment: What I need to do in Azure Storage side? @JimXu

Comment: In normal, we do not need to do anything in Azure Storage side.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of important points to note while mounting Storage accounts in Azure Databricks.

> For Azure Blob storage: `source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<directory-name>"`

> For Azure Data Lake Storage gen2: `source = "abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/"`

To mount an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 filesystem or a folder inside it as Azure Databricks file system, the URL should be like `abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/`

[image]

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.